# How can I append value by getting values from other lists same index and form a new list based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

(MY INPUT):
I have 4 lists as below , and each list contains 8 values.

```
eventIdList=['112','114','115','117','198','125','138','107'] ## No duplicate value inside, like primary key. 

eventTypeList=[fuel,driver,driver,trax,driver,fuel,lux,driver] ## duplicate values exist inside.

partnerIdList= ['aux','box','box','disc','box','cot','top','box' ] ## duplicate values exist inside.

customerIdList= ['dell','apple','apple','amazon','apple','microsoft','dell','apple'] ## duplicate values exist inside.
```

First payload I am getting for index 0 as below. Similarly other indexes inside the for loop.

```
"message":{

"eventId": '112',

"eventType": 'fuel',

"partnerId": 'aux'

"customerId": 'dell'

}
```

Observe 4 lists in Input, Except the eventId, 1st, 2nd and 7th index of all the payloads (eventType, partnerId and customerId value)  is same {'driver','box','apple'}. So I need to display-- those event ids in a list, appending the eventId values by iteration, Here eventId should be as [114,115,107]. How can I achieve it?

### OUTPUT Expecting under for loop

when index is 1
"message":{

```
eventId: [114],

eventType: "driver",

partnerId: "box"

customerId: "apple"

}
```

when index is 2
"message":{

```
eventId: [114,115],

eventType: "driver",

partnerId: "box"

customerId: "apple"

}
```

when index is 7
"message":{

```
eventId: [114,115,107],

eventType: "driver",

partnerId: "box"

customerId: "apple"

}
```

---

### My code something like this. not completed.

```
def myAppendFunction(eventIdList, eventTypeList, customerIdList, partnerIdList):

    formedEventIdList=[]

    for inc , eventIdelem in  enumerate(eventIdList):

      

       print('inc**',inc) 

       print('eventid**',eventIdelem) 

       print('eventType**', eventTypeList[inc])

       print('customerId**', customerIdList[inc])

       print('partnerId**', partnerIdList[inc])

           

            #LOGIC WANT

            # if (eventTypeList[inc]==eventTypeList[inc+1]) and (customerIdList[inc]==customerIdList[inc+1]) and (partnerIdList[inc]==partnerIdList[inc+1]) :           

 

       #formedEventIdList.append(eventIdelem)

 

            message = {"Type": "Notification",

            "Message": {"eventType": eventType,"customerId": customerId,"partnerId": partnerId, "eventIds": formedEventIdList}

            }

#for end
```

AGAIN GIVING My **PROGRAM**, **OUTPUT** and **Expected OUTPUT** Below. Please give me the Code which can work for me here.

### My Python PROGRAM below:

```
eventIdList=['112','114','115','117','198','125','138','107'] 
eventTypeList=['fuel','driver','driver','trax','driver','fuel','lux','driver'] ## duplicate values (like driver, fuel etc) is exist in eventTypeList, 
partnerIdList= ['aux','box','box','disc','box','cot','top','box' ] ## duplicate values exist in partnerIdList like box
customerIdList= ['dell','apple','apple','amazon','apple','microsoft','dell','apple'] ## duplicate values is exist like apple, dell etc in customerIdList
for inc , eventIdelem in  enumerate(eventIdList):
   formTheEventIdList=[]
   message = {
    "Message": {"eventType": eventTypeList[inc],"customerId": customerIdList[inc],"eventIds": eventIdelem,"partnerId": partnerIdList[inc]}       
    }
   print('inc=',inc,'OUTPUT*********:: ', message)
```

### OUTPUT of this program below:

inc= 0 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'fuel', 'customerId': 'dell', 'eventIds': '112', 'partnerId': 'aux'}}

inc= 1 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'driver', 'customerId': 'apple', 'eventIds': '114', 'partnerId': 'box'}}

inc= 2 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'driver', 'customerId': 'apple', 'eventIds': '115', 'partnerId': 'box'}}

inc= 3 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'trax', 'customerId': 'amazon', 'eventIds': '117', 'partnerId': 'disc'}}

inc= 4 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'driver', 'customerId': 'apple', 'eventIds': '198', 'partnerId': 'box'}}

inc= 5 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'fuel', 'customerId': 'microsoft', 'eventIds': '125', 'partnerId': 'cot'}}

inc= 6 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'lux', 'customerId': 'dell', 'eventIds': '138', 'partnerId': 'top'}}

inc= 7 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'driver', 'customerId': 'apple', 'eventIds': '107', 'partnerId': 'box'}}

### But I WANT OUTPUT as below:

inc= 0 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'fuel', 'customerId': 'dell', 'eventIds': ['112'], 'partnerId': 'aux'}}

inc= 1 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'driver', 'customerId': 'apple', 'eventIds': **['114']**, 'partnerId': 'box'}}

inc= 2 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'driver', 'customerId': 'apple', 'eventIds': **['115',114]**, 'partnerId': 'box'}}

inc= 3 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'trax', 'customerId': 'amazon', 'eventIds': ['117'], 'partnerId': 'disc'}}

inc= 4 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'driver', 'customerId': 'apple', 'eventIds': ['198'], 'partnerId': 'box'}}

inc= 5 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'fuel', 'customerId': 'microsoft', 'eventIds': ['125'], 'partnerId': 'cot'}}

inc= 6 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'lux', 'customerId': 'dell', 'eventIds': ['138'], 'partnerId': 'top'}}

inc= 7 OUTPUT*********::  {'Message': {'eventType': 'driver', 'customerId': 'apple', 'eventIds': **['107',115,114]**, 'partnerId': 'box'}}

========================

**NOTE: Only those records which have same 'eventType', 'customerId' and 'partnerId'. store those eventIds and display in a list there.**
[when 'eventType','customerId' and 'partnerId' have same values, matches with other index, then append the eventID. Here when index=1,2 and 7.
So in this case need to append 'eventIds' in a list and display]

*[when index=0,3,4,5,6]  'eventType', 'customerId' and 'partnerId' values all 3 are not matching with other records/indices. So not required to append in this case.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sorry, I can't understand the question. Which of these is the input to the program? Exactly what should the output be, and what is the logic behind that output? When you run the program, what output do you get, and *how is that different* from the desired output? I see you have had the account for over 8 years, but this seems to be your first question or answer - I am a bit confused.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have had an account for 6 years before I gave my first answer. I never asked a question. What's confusing about that?

Comment: Sorry Carl. Stackoverflow added my output in the function. 4 Lists are the INPUTs given top of same length. My OUTPUT should be like below expecting.  Based on the common eventType, partnerId and customerId of each payload, the eventid i need to append in a list inside a for loop.  OUTPUT expecting to display as below. "message":{
eventId: [114,115,107],
eventType: "driver",
partnerId: "box"
customerId: "apple"
}

Comment: Can someone please answer my question. I gave the Program, output and expected output..

Answer (score -1):

Iterating on four lists simultaneously can be done conveniently with `zip`.

Filtering elements that meet a certain condition can be done with a list comprehension.

```py
eventIdList=['112','114','115','117','198','125','138','107'] ## No duplicate value inside, like primary key. 

eventTypeList=['fuel','driver','driver','trax','driver','fuel','lux','driver'] ## duplicate values exist inside.

partnerIdList= ['aux','box','box','disc','box','cot','top','box' ] ## duplicate values exist inside.

customerIdList= ['dell','apple','apple','amazon','apple','microsoft','dell','apple'] ## duplicate values exist inside.

def filterPartnerId(goodPartnerId, eventIdList, eventTypeList, partnerIdList, customerIdList):
    return [(evId, evType, pId, cId) for (evId, evType, pId, cId) in zip(eventIdList, eventTypeList, partnerIdList, customerIdList) if pId == goodPartnerId]

print(filterPartnerId("box", eventIdList, eventTypeList, partnerIdList, customerIdList))
# [('114', 'driver', 'box', 'apple'),
#  ('115', 'driver', 'box', 'apple'),
#  ('198', 'driver', 'box', 'apple'),
#  ('107', 'driver', 'box', 'apple')]
```

You could also convert your four lists into one list of dicts:

```py
def fourlists_to_onelist(eventIdList, eventTypeList, partnerIdList, customerIdList):
    return [{"eventId": evId, "eventType": evType, "partnerId": pId, "customerId": cId} for (evId, evType, pId, cId) in zip(eventIdList, eventTypeList, partnerIdList, customerIdList)]

def filterPartnerId(goodPartnerId, onelist):
    return [x for x in onelist if x['partnerId'] == goodPartnerId]

onelist = fourlists_to_onelist(eventIdList, eventTypeList, partnerIdList, customerIdList)
print(filterPartnerId("box", onelist))
# [{'eventId': '114', 'eventType': 'driver', 'partnerId': 'box', 'customerId': 'apple'},
#  {'eventId': '115', 'eventType': 'driver', 'partnerId': 'box', 'customerId': 'apple'},
#  {'eventId': '198', 'eventType': 'driver', 'partnerId': 'box', 'customerId': 'apple'},
#  {'eventId': '107', 'eventType': 'driver', 'partnerId': 'box', 'customerId': 'apple'}]
```

You can also find which element is the most common in a list, using  `statistics.mode`:

```py
from statistics import mode

goodPartnerId = mode(partnerIdList)
print(goodPartnerId)
# box
```

Comment: If the question is not clear, please use the comments instead; and if appropriate, vote to close with that reason. We should not have to guess what the question really is - especially since the point of the site is to leave behind a question that *others* could find with a search engine.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I chose to give an answer solving the OP's issue rather than vote to close the question without answering it. I felt that would be more helpful.

Comment: How can you say that the answer solves OP's issue, if the question is not clear?

Comment: And more importantly: how does it help the _next_ person with this problem, whatever it turns out to be, and the person after that, and...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have never, ever posted an answer with absolute 100% certainty that I had fully comprehended the question.That is the nature of communication, especially when in written form over the internet without hearing or seeing the writer. It occasionally happens that I misunderstood the question, and the OP clarifies their question after reading my answer, and I have to go back and delete or edit my answer. That is always a risk.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Would it help the next person *more* if I didn't give an answer at all?

Comment: @Stef yes, because it increases the likelihood that the OP edits to something comprehensible and discoverable, and that when the next person arrives they can determine whether they're in the right place.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I seriously doubt that the silent treatment would increase the likelihood that the OP will edit their question.

Comment: What "silent treatment"? There's _already_ a comment asking for clarification. And when it gets closed as unclear there's a banner linking to help.

Comment: Dear Bros-  @Karl Knechtel, Stef,  jonrsharpe , I posted my question with the better english i know tried to explain. Like example program, the output. and expected Output which i am looking help from you. can you please help me to share the piece of code which can be suitable there. thank you all.

Comment: @Stef bro - I posted my question with the program again, also posted the expected Output. Can someone please guide me with the piece of code which can be helpful, similar to your previous code.  filterPartnerId(goodPartnerId) ..  which can give the appropriate output. Thanks in advance..